# JSTL, jsp and Dojo parsing issue

Tags: jsp, templates, dojo, jstl

I have a dojo widget with templateString that looks like

```
  <div>${buttonLabel}</div>
```

. The widget is in the jstl/jsp.

When the jsp gets parsed, the `${buttonLabel}` is parsed to empty and now the template becomes `<div></div>` with this the dojo template mixin could not identify to substitute the string.

Is there a way to avoid the jstl/jsp parsing in the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround for this issue. The problem is that the JSP variables syntax is the same as DOJO's ones and you have to escape the dojo's variables with \
 ****${buttonLabel}

Comment: I would try it and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You can set any default value for ${buttonLabel} in the template's JS file.

```
buttonLabel: 'someValue',

//other code
constructor:function(){
}
```

Comment: But the JS itself is a third party and we dont have control in it. Is there a way to avoid this parsing from the JSP parsers?

Comment: I also dont prefer to extend the widget and overwrite fields in my custom widget.

Comment: Setting some value for the variable using JSTL variable syntax may help you. Give this a try  : <c:set var="buttonLabel"  value="<div></div>"/>